# Sending Authentication Header using Curl and PHP

Tags: php, api, authentication, curl

I'm trying to use an API that requires authentication with a private key pair.

**Here is the API documentation:**

[Authentication API Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OjTk.png)

[SubmitOrder API Docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3EJr.png)

This is my code. I'm not getting any errors, but no trades are being placed. My coding skills are not the sharpest and without errors, I'm stuck!

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Generate random amount between 28.00 and 30.00

$ran1 = mt_rand(2800, 3000);
$ran2 = $ran1/100;

// Config

$sAPIKey = "mykey"; // private key
$sAPISecret = "mysecret"; // api secret

$sPair = "GLD_BTC";
// $sAmount = "1.00";
$sRate = "0.0001";
$sNonce = time();

// Request

$sRequest = "https://tradesatoshi.com/api/private/submitorder?API_PUBLIC_KEY=" . $sAPIKey . "&Market=" . $sPair . "&Type=" . 'Buy' . "&Amount=" . $ran2 . "&Price=" . $sRate . "&nonce=" . $sNonce;

$sSign=hash_hmac('sha512', $sRequest, $sAPISecret);

$ch = curl_init($sRequest);

// disable cert validation
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);  // shouldn't need this

// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:' . $sSign));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('apisign:' . $sSign));

$execResult = curl_exec($ch);

?>
```

Any guidance would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: what's the content of $execResult when it comes back?

Comment: I put an 'echo $execResult;' under the last line and it seems to come back empty?